# Does GSM mobile phones have an RFID chip per default?

Tags: mobile-phones, rfid

I heard something funny the other day, that I'm not sure that I trust, but at the same time I'm curious if I'm mistaken.

What I heard was that *every* GSM mobile phone has an RFID chip in them, because the SIM card functions as an RFID chip. Is this true or false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how this is programming related, but anyway.

A SIM card does provide "ID" for a wireless ("RF") device, however, it does not provide RFID functionality under the common RFID definition. (A SIM card does not send an ID via RF)

SIM:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_Identity_Module

RFID:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFID

Comment: Aha, thank you. I asked the question here because I'm doing a project that involves positioning and I was thinking about taking an RFID approach if possible.